# Open Source Executable Editor

Tags: c++, security

I have a native C++ windows app that i would like to edit. Are there any open source tools for me to do this on Windows? I want to edit the executable directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Allow me to direct you toward [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10426/what-is-a-good-windows-hex-editor-viewer), the accepted answer of which links to [this hex editor comparison chart, including license info](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_hex_editors).

Comment: I'll go with the plugin for Notepad++ - I already use this as my primary editor.

Comment: I use that one a bit myself:)